# How to SqlCeDataReader iterate twice

Tags: c#, .net

I have a object called:

```
SqlCeDataReader rdr;
```

Because `SqlCeDataReader` does not have HasRows function, I wrote one:

```
if (!HasRows(rdr)) // Iterate to find number of rows
{
}

while (rdr.Read()) // Read the reader
{
}
```

The rdr.Read() does not return any result.

If I comment out the first iteration, It return result.

Thank you.

Comment: [SqlCeDataReader.HasRows Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedatareader.hasrows.aspx)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't iterate twice - SqlCeDataReader "provides a way of reading a *forward-only* stream of data rows from a data source." - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedatareader.aspx).

But it does have a [`HasRows` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedatareader.hasrows.aspx) - just use that?

Comment: The problem is it return me +  rdr.HasRows 'rdr.HasRows' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' bool {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: base {System.SystemException} = {"SQL Server Compact does not support calls to HasRows property if the underlying cursor is not scrollable."}

Comment: I think have to use SqlDataAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

I am also not sure of how to do it properly, but on my app i wrote something like

```
using (SqlCeDataReader rdr = sceCmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    int i = 0;
    while (rdr.Read())
    { 
        // some other code here
        i++;
    }
    rdr.close();
    if(i==0)
    {
        // something to say if its empty
        Console.WriteLine("No data found.");
    } else {
        // something else to say if its not empty
        Console.WriteLine(i + "data found.");
    }
}
```